# How do I convert SVG with image links to PNG/JPEG?

Tags: svg, imagemagick, png, fabricjs

I'm using `fabric.js` to add and manipulate images on canvas element. I'd like to export the final result to an image file (JPEG/PNG), and have tried several approaches, without much luck.

The first was using the HTML5 `canvas.toDataURL` callback - didn't work (apparently this cannot be done with cross-origin images).

I then tried to export the canvas to SVG and use `convert` utility:

```
$ convert file.svg file.png
```

The SVG looks a bit like this:

```
<svg>
    ...
    <image xlink:href="http://example.com/images/image.png"
    style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; fill: rgb(0,0,0); opacity: 1;"
    transform="translate(-160 -247.5)" width="320" height="495">
    </image>
    ...
</svg>
```

That also didn't work, presumably because of the image links. I then tried to download the linked image and store it locally, replacing the `http://...image.png` link with `/path/to/image.png`. No luck.

Is there a way to make this happen? thanks.

---

### UPDATE

I've since solved this by using fabric's node module (`npm install fabric`) and simply using fabric's JSON representation of the canvas (`canvas.toJSON()` in fabric) to generate an image (also uses canvas module - `npm install canvas`).

Here's a simple example on how to do this:

```
// import the fabric module
var fabric = require('fabric').fabric,
    fs = require('fs');

// read the fabric json data as string
// (from file, db, etc)
var jsonString = readJSON(filepath);

// create canvas with specified dimensions
// (change to match your needs)
canvas = fabric.createCanvasForNode(100, 100);

// create output file to hold the png image
output = fs.createWriteStream("/tmp/image.png")

// load the json to the canvas and
// pipe the output to the png file
canvas.loadFromJSON(jsonString, function() {
  var stream = canvas.createPNGStream();
  stream.pipe(output)
});
```

Comment: We'll have support for cross-origin images in Fabric soon — https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/263 Meanwhile, is there a way for you to store images on the same server (to satisfy SOP)?

Comment: That's awesome - thanks for all your hard work. 

Yeah, I suppose I could fetch the images as I go. I did notice that `canvas.toDataURL()` works when the images are stored on the same server. I'll do that for now.

Comment: You could also data encode your bitmap image and assign it as a URL.

Comment: any Help on above Question?

Comment: The same Problem I am Facing as well :(